# Joining three tables together based on common ids

Tags: mysql, sql

[image]

What I'm looking to generate is the **wp_tylerposts** table as it is, with the same specifications as the query (selecting only those with *post_type='sponsor'*, but I'd like to reference the other two tables (*object_id* from **wp_tylerterm_relationships** and the corresponding *name* from **wp_tylerterms**) so that added on to wp_tylerpostswould be the corresponding ***name*** value from wp_tylerterms (added to the table would be "Gold Sponsors", for example).

Hopefully that makes sense. I'm sure there's a pretty simple solution, and I've tried my hand at some join  queries without any luck... haven't done any of the stuff in a long time. Any help would be much appreciated!

Edit: I've come closer, I think, but I still can't retrieve the "name" column value from wp_tylerterms, here's what I have:

```
SELECT 
    c.ID, c.post_title, a.name
FROM 
    wp_tylerposts c
LEFT JOIN
    wp_tylerterm_relationships b
ON
    c.ID = b.object_id
LEFT JOIN
    wp_tylerterms a
ON
    b.object_id = a.term_id
WHERE
    c.post_type = 'sponsor'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In second `join`, you use `b.object_id` instead of `b.term_taxonomy_id`. Your query should look like this:

```
SELECT 
    c.ID, c.post_title, a.name
FROM 
    wp_tylerposts c
LEFT JOIN
    wp_tylerterm_relationships b
ON
    c.ID = b.object_id
LEFT JOIN
    wp_tylerterms a
ON
    b.term_taxonomy_id = a.term_id
WHERE
    c.post_type = 'sponsor'
```